# Which antivirus is good for my typical usage?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus

I've got Windows XP and use MS Office and Arstisteer and browse the web. My McAfee expired and I'm about to renew it and would like to know if you think I'm doing the right thing buying it from McAffee or if you have something else to say about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'm a fan of Nod32 as it has a small footprint and is resource-friendly. However, recently I have uninstalled all 3rd party AV programs and started using Microsoft Security Essentials, Microsoft's own, free, Antivirus product. I have been fine with it on Windows 7, but it is also available on XP. If you dislike it, you can then always try another product.

http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx

http://mse.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/A/3/8/A38FFBF2-1122-48B4-AF60-E44F6DC28BD8/enus/x86/mseinstall.exe